# Is it possible to use the Nelder-Mead optimization algorithm to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, implementation

I am currently working on a project where I am implementing various non-gradient optimization algorithms to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP).

I was able to get a Genetic Algorithm to work pretty well and am now looking at other options like Nelder-Mead (NM) and Particle Swarm. Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time coming up with an implementation for NM since the "variables" are **permutations of cities rather than numeric values.**

Is there a way to implement NM to solve the TSP? More specifically, I can't figure out how to calculate the "centroid" of permutations and/or reflect over it to find a new permutation.

Comment: Does it have to be NM specifically? TSP can be formulated as an ILP instance, then you have numeric values, but applying NM would be strange.

Comment: It doesn't! I'm really just curious what the implementation would look like because I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around it. Also, what's an ILP distance?

Comment: ILP is integer linear programming, the formulations are given on the [wikipedia article of TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Integer_linear_programming_formulations)